# How to write this in summation notation $f^0(k^n)+f(k^{n+1})+f^2(k^{n+2})+f^3(k^{n+3})+\dots +f^{n+p-1}(k^{n+p-1}) $?

Tags: summation

I have function $f$, where $f^n$ denotes composition and $0<k<1$. I need to write the following in summation notation:

$$f^0(k^n)+f(k^{n+1})+f^2(k^{n+2})+f^3(k^{n+3})+\dots +f^{n+p-1}(k^{n+p-1})  $$

I should be able to write something like this?

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n+p-1}f^i(k^{?})$$

Comment: I think you have a typo. Shouldn't your last term be $f^{p-1}(k^{n+p-1})$?

Comment: You are right Siddharth. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last term is instead supposed to be $f^{p-1}(k^{n+p-1})$, then the sum is
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}f^i(k^{n+i}).$$
Otherwise, you need to explain the pattern.

Comment: Yes, you are right. , last term is $f^{p-1}(k^{n+p-1})$. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In summation notation it should be \begin{equation} \sum_{i=0}^{n+p-1}f^i(k^{n+i}).\end{equation}

So the exponent of $k$ in the last term should be $2n+p-1$.